# ActiveRecord erring with: missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working to enable a User soft delete in my app with User.delete_at. When that field is set, I don't want deleted users returned throughout the app. So I setup the following given I have the following models:

```
User.rb
    has_many :groups, :through => :group_members, :conditions => ['banned = ?', false]
    default_scope :conditions => 'users.deleted_at IS NULL'

Group.rb
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :group_members, :dependent => :destroy, :include => :user, :conditions => ['banned = ?', false]

GroupMember.rb
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
    default_scope joins(:user).where('users.deleted_at IS NULL')
```

Then problem now is that when I run:

```
current_user.groups
```

I get the following error:

```
    Group Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "group_members" ON "groups"."id" = "group_members"."group_id" WHERE "group_members"."user_id" = 1 AND (users.deleted_at IS NULL) AND (banned = 'f')
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users"
LINE 1: ..."group_id" WHERE "group_members"."user_id" = 1 AND (users.dele...
```

Is there a better way to make it so that User.delete_at users don't get returned throughout the app? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your

```
.where('users.deleted_at IS NULL')
```

condition should be in :conditions for `has_many` in group model...